# Change value for a records in collection using aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregate-functions

have a collection like this , how to change a particular value from true to fail with out modifying other values

```
_id:ObjectId('......')
ton_id :ObjectId('abcd')
value:true
date:2018-1-13T07:09:40.075+00:00



_id:ObjectId('......')
ton_id :ObjectId('abcd1')
value:no result
date:2018-12-13T07:09:40.075+00:00
```

change value from true to fail, using aggregation only

expected output:

```
_id:ObjectId('......')
ton_id :ObjectId('abcd')
value:fail
date:2018-1-13T07:09:40.075+00:00



_id:ObjectId('......')
ton_id :ObjectId('abcd1')
value:no result
date:2018-12-13T07:09:40.075+00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer [update aggregate results in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572209/update-aggregate-results-in-mongodb)

Do you specifically want to use aggregate and not findOneAndUpdate? As this can be achieved quite easily I think by doing something like below inside a for loop.

```
 module.exports = {
  async updateGCGuideSent() {
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Booking = mongoose.model('Booking');
    findObject = {remindGuides: false}; 
    update = {remindGuides: true};
    await Booking.findOneAndUpdate(findObject, update, {new: true}, (err, doc) => {
      console.log(update);
    });
  },
};
```

Comment: Ok, did you check the top answer in the link? May be of some help.